# Open local file in web browser in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I'd like to open a local file (rust documentation under `~/.rustup/`), but I'm on Ubuntu 23.10 and both Chrome and Firefox are running inside some sort of container system and so can't access the local file system.

What's an easy option to be able to open local files when I need to?

Comment: BTW, one can install Ubuntu packages directly from Mozilla as PPA: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/, not running in a SNAP container. A few issues I had with SNAP were large size, since all dependencies are included, and lethargic update -- Thunderbird and p7Zip were hardly ever updated, for example. (7-Zip runs in wine, and Thunderbird is now updated from Mozilla PPA.)

Answer (score 1):

Move the file directly into your home directory. At least for Ubuntu's Firefox, it is specifically access to "dotfiles" that is blocked (by Snap's AppArmor rules), while access to other files under your home isn't.

Alternatively – install Firefox from its official `.deb` package.